# Compiling my own PHP extension on Windows with Visual Studio 2008

Tags: php, windows, visual-studio-2008, php-extension

I wrote a PHP extension and it could be compiled and run under linux successfully. But on windows, I met some problems.

I did the compiling on windows according to http://blog.slickedit.com/?p=128 with PHP source version 5.2.10, and after the compiling it generated the dll file. But when I tried to use the dll file, it reported me the memory problems when starting Apache(Wamp server). And then I started the debugging process, it seemed that REGISTER_INI_ENTRIES() had problems.

Here is the PHP extension source code, http://www.bluefly.cn/xsplit.tar.gz , and it works fine on Linux. But I also want to make it work on Windows.

Sorry I am not a pro so that I hope someone can help me.

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance~

Comment: Is there any complete guide of doing such stuff on Windows?

Comment: Sorry. Have no answer for you, but if you get this running, could you please leave a very short comment about the performance gain you achieved and your overall impression? THX in advance...

Comment: @merkuro, it works very well under Linux and it is really fast and reliable(time tested). But I really dont know how to get this work on Windows

Comment: Can you make the source code available? The link above returns a 404 error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're not seeing an issue on Linux is most likely that you're doing a thread safebuild on windows, but not on Linux. Try adding `--enable-maintainer-zts` on Linux and then check using valgrind (`USE_ZEND_ALLOC=0 valgrind /usr/bin/php script.php`)

From a quick glanceover your code I saw that you didn't define your `php_xsplit_init_globals` which initialized thread variables. Tis function has to be registered from `MINIT` by adding a

```
ZEND_INIT_MODULE_GLOBALS(xsplit, php_yplist_init_globals, NULL);
```

call. Maybe something else is wrong, but that's the first thing I saw.

Answer (score 2):

Wamp is compiled using VC6 and it requires your module to be compiled with VC6.

Reporting Romain Bourdon (author of WampServer) words : Because Apache is compiled with VC6, if you want to run PHP as a module (as in WampServer) you must compile the module with VC6.

If you want to compile your module with a more recent platform, you have to compile your entire PHP-CGI distribution and run it as a (fast-)CGI.

If you can read french (or if you do know how to use a translator) you can read [this post](http://blog.wampserver.com/index.php/2009/11/04/php5-3-sous-windows-plus-de-nouveautes-quon-le-croit/).