# Compiling a PHP extension for windows

Tags: php, php-extension

I've previously managed to get [XHP](https://github.com/facebook/xhp) compiled in a Linux environment with the `.so` extension. I'm trying to compile it for use in a windows enviroment (`.dll`) and I've followed the following [tutorial](https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild) on php.net but after I `buildconf`, I fail to see the extension under `configure --help` (I downloaded the source at put the source folder in `ext` directory).  Any help would be appreciated.

I'm using Visual studio 2008 and looking to compile extension for PHP 5.4.

Comment: Some more info on what compiler you're using might be useful... Visual Studio, codeblocks,... ?

Comment: I'm using Visual studio 2008 and compiling extension for PHP 5.4

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036110/compiling-my-own-php-extension-on-windows-with-visual-studio-2008

Answer (score 1):

XHP doesn't have a `config.w32` file to support the Windows build environment (see [Build for Windows](https://github.com/facebook/xhp/issues/20).

Windows uses a different build system than Linux so it requires a different config. I remember manually converting a `config.m4` to a `config.w32` for a tutorial on how to write your own PHP extension and it was relatively painless. It could have been that way because it was simple compared to [XHP's config.m4](https://github.com/facebook/xhp/blob/master/config.m4).

It wouldn't hurt to copy the contents of `config.m4` to `config.w32` and try to build it to see what happens.